# R upgrade to 3.4 installing packages

Tags: r

I had R working perfectly until I decided to upgrade to 3.4. Now I am unable to install packages.

while installing packages I get an error

```
Installing package into ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages("ggplot2") :
  'lib = "/usr/local/lib/R/site-library"' is not writable
Would you like to use a personal library instead?  (y/n)
```

If I hit yes I get

```
Would you like to create a personal library
NA
to install packages into?  (y/n)
```

at which point it proceeds give this error

```
Error in install.packages("quantstrat") : unable to create ‘NA’
```

Comment: Set `.libPaths()` to a directory where you have write permissions.

Comment: you can uncomment the R_LIBS_USER or (set a new path) in /etc/R/Renviron

Comment: This worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why R 3.4.1 changes the library path. To change it back, simply edit `/etc/R/Renviron`:

```
$ sudo gedit /etc/R/Renviron
```

Comment-out `R_LIBS_SITE=...` then uncomment `R_LIBS_USER=...`

```
# edd Jun 2017  Comment-out R_LIBS_USER
R_LIBS_USER=${R_LIBS_USER-'~/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4'}

# edd Apr 2003  Allow local install in /usr/local, also add a directory for
#               Debian packaged CRAN packages, and finally the default dir 
# edd Jul 2007  Now use R_LIBS_SITE, not R_LIBS
#R_LIBS_SITE=${R_LIBS_SITE-'/usr/local/lib/R/site-library:/usr/lib/R/site-library:/usr/lib/R/library'}
```