# Console was stuck on a runApp message or " Loading required package: shiny"

Tags: r, shiny, deployment, flexdashboard

I have built a Shiny flexdashaboard at local, but my shinyapp only works occassionally. Sometimes the console pops up the message loading required packages: shiny, lisiting on [url], and the shiny stucks. I have looked for the different solutions onlinea and tried them all. For example, I have reinstalled my R studio, updated my both R and R studio to the newest version. An old post suggesting that it is due to a mismatch in the libraries built and Rstudio built.
(Details: (1)https://community.rstudio.com/t/shiny-apps-not-loading-on-r-version-4-1-0/110522/11
(2) https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/upgrade-R.html )

However, I have checked my installed packages, it seemed all of my packages are up-to-date.
Can anyone help me? I would really appreciate for you help.....

[Whenever this message pops up my shiny flexdashboard cant run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DBvA3.png)

[and it will just become something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ad9Q0.jpg)

[My built vs version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6EobV.png)
[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b8U80.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CTS3V.png)

I would like my app to run normally.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @喵喵兔: Look at about `R_LIBS_USER`and `R_LIBS_SITE` in `Renviron`. The path library of Shiny server are not necessarily the same of the user. Look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44873430/r-upgrade-to-3-4-installing-packages/44896126#44896126